# Simple Chatbot generates an error in Anaconda/Python

Tags: python, chatbot

I copied this little Python Code for a chatbot.

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
pairs = [
[
    r"my name is (.*)",
    ["Hello %1, How are you today ?",]
],
[
    r"what is your name ?",
    ["My name is Chatty and I'm a chatbot ?",]
],
[
    r"how are you ?",
    ["I'm doing good\nHow about You ?",]
],
[
    r"what (.*) want ?",
    ["Make me an offer I can't refuse",]       
],

]

my_dummy_reflections= {
 "go"     : "gone",
 "hello"    : "hey there"
}

def chatty():
    print("Hi, I'm Chatty and I chat alot ;)\nPlease type lowercase English language to start a 
conversation. Type quit to leave ") #default message at the start
#chat = Chat(pairs, reflections)
chat = Chat(pairs, my_dummy_reflections) #THIS IS THE PROBEM!!
chat.converse()
if __name__ == "__main__":
chatty()
```

The errorcode I get is:

```
File "<tokenize>", line 87
chat = Chat(pairs, my_dummy_reflections)
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I do not understand the problem in Python. It is at the end of the script and it is concerning the function CHAT with 2 parameters...
THANKS for your help!!

Comment: Missing a tab before the code ? this is a problem of indentation, python work with the indentation

Comment: The reason you see the error reported on the wrong line is probably that you did not properly save the code before running it. Otherwise it might be necessary to restart the interpreter. The part of the Python implementation that reports the error to you, knows which line the error occurred on from the exception itself, but it has to look back at the source code file to show you that line, and it's looking at different source code vs. what was run.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation and you should [read about it](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) to understand it better.

So basically in line 28, there's a tab missing.

It is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
chatty()
```

And it should be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    chatty()
```